# Creating a line graph with ggplot library which plots two lines (the high and low of stock prices) on the same graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, ggplot2

I can plot the closing prices using the below syntax:

```
gg = ggplot(stock_prices.ix['2013-01-01': '2013-12-31'], aes('date', 'close')) + geom_line()
```

However, I don't know how to plot the "high" and "low" prices on the same plot, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The standard practice of plotting "High" and "Lows" (together with "Open" and "Close) in Finance is candlestick plotting.
The following code should get you started in charting candlesticks:

**Step 1. Imports.**

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data
```

**Step 2. Downloads.**

```
start = dt.datetime(2015,1,1)
spy = data.DataReader('^GSPC', 'yahoo', start)
```

You can easily skip this step if you already have your data in OHLC format.

**Step 3. Prepare your data.**

At this point you would have your data in the form:

```
spy.head()
                   Open       High         Low        Close    Volume   Adj Close
Date                        
2015-01-02  2058.899902 2072.360107 2046.040039 2058.199951 2708700000  2058.199951
2015-01-05  2054.439941 2054.439941 2017.339966 2020.579956 3799120000  2020.579956
2015-01-06  2022.150024 2030.250000 1992.439941 2002.609985 4460110000  2002.609985
2015-01-07  2005.550049 2029.609985 2005.550049 2025.900024 3805480000  2025.900024
2015-01-08  2030.609985 2064.080078 2030.609985 2062.139893 3934010000  2062.139893
```

To move further, you would need to have your index in a separate column as number of dates, rather than as a timestamp, which is achieved by:

```
spy['Date2'] = spy.index.map(lambda x: mdates.date2num(x))
```

**Step 4. Candlestick plotting.**

Now that you have all the data in place you can plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d"))
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.title("SP500")
candlestick_ohlc(ax, spy[['Date2', 'Open', 'High', 'Low','Close']].values, width=.6, colorup='g', alpha =.4);
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Should you still wish to have just 2 separate lines for High and Low the following line of code will do just that:

```
spy[['High','Low']].plot();
```

[image]